# Enum properties, Web API, JSON deserialization and typos

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

Let's say we got a class like this one:

```
public class Person
{
     [JsonConstructor]
     public Person(string name, DayOfWeek bornOnDay) => (Name, BornOnDay) = (name, bornOnDay);

     public string Name { get; protected set; }

     public DayOfWeek BornOnDay { get; protected set; }
}
```

And an endpoint like this one:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/people")]
public IHttpActionResult PostPerson([FromBody]List<Person> people)
{
     // whatever
}
```

I've noticed that if I make a typo in `enum` type when making a request - no error occurs, only the object that has the erroneous `enum` won't be deserialized.

For instance, the request body may look like this:

```
[{"name":"John", "bornOnDay":"Moonday",},
 {"name":"Mark", "bornOnDay":"Friday",},]
```

Endpoint will receive the list containing one `Person`, Mark, born on Friday.

I would like to make the post operation either happen completely, or fail, not with only with the objects without `enum` typos.. Is there a way to do it, without receiving a `string` instead of `DayOfWeek`, and then using `Enum.TryParse(...)` to determine that the input was erroneous?

Edit:

I actually want the error to occur, and be detectable, so I can return `400` code to the client.

Comment: Since your enum is not nullable, what if you add a default value like "None" on your enum, then in your constructor, you can do a check if value is "None", if it is, it's was either misspelled or not set at all, and you can throw an error.

Comment: can you try out solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this , you can create enum value from string you have inputted

```
public class Person
{
     private string day;
     [JsonConstructor]
     public Person(string name, string bornOnDay){
         this.Name = name;
         this.day = bornOnDay;
     }

     public string Name { get; protected set; }

     public DayOfWeek BornOnDay { 
     get {
          DayOfWeek  weekday;
          if(Enum.TryParse(day, true, out weekday))
            return weekday;  
          else
            return DayOfWeek.None;//add none if no able to parse
     }
 }
```

Note : `None` is added according to [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) to avoid issues related to `null` value in system.

Comment: I made a slight change to your proposed solution. I made the enum nullable, so I could use .NET built-in enum DayOfWeek.

Comment: @Shocky2- i suggest dont do it , follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern .. as null create lot of issue, that is the reason i suggested to add `None` as one of the enum

Comment: This will do parsing on every access to the BornOnDay. Also there's no reason to have the if statement. The parsing will default to 0(which is equal to None) anyway. And if you are ok with that, then you don't need the custom parser in the first place. Since DayOfWeek is not nullable, if the Deserializer wasnt able to get the value, it will default to 0. Literally no custom logic is needed for that.

Comment: What if I am using an enum from a library that I can't alter? Nullable is a satisfactory solution in that case.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public class Person
{
     [JsonProperty]
     public string Name { get; protected set; }

     [JsonProperty]
     private string _BornOnDay { set {
       //try parse the string, if not successful, throw a nicely
       //formatted error with the original string and what you expect,
       //if parse is successful, set the value to BornOnDay;
     }}

     [JsonIgnore]
     public DayOfWeek BornOnDay { get; protected set; }
}
```

Not sure about the JsonConstructor attribute, never needed to use it. If you do need it and if I understand it correctly you can have something similar with it. Deserializer should give a string into constructor, and then inside of it, you do parsing logic for the enum yourself.

Comment: That doesn't work because the exception is thrown before the endpoint code starts executing. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As in because you can't put your controller body into try catch block? You should have a global exception handler which takes care of things like that, so that you are not limited by where the error occurs. There's some built in functionality, like HttpResponseException which takes a status code in its constructor. So you can throw it from anywhere.

Comment: That way you have one object, which you can put in any method, and one global exception handler, and it will take care of itself wherever you use it, instead of needing to do checks on every method body and format an error again and again.

Comment: It won't be caught in the global exception handler. I tried it. It will produce the same result as I mentioned in the question, which is undesirable. You can't detect it in this scenario. If it is possible to detect it, please, show me how.